# Remove null values from whole data in Power BI

Tags: null, powerbi, data-cleaning

I have 20+ tables and also there are a lot more columns so it's is not possible to filter out null values one by one for each column, Is there any alternative to remove null values from whole data in one go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

filter all null values for multiple columns at one time with the M Query below

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(Record.ToList(_),null)=false)
```

This will help.

Answer (score 0):

or an easy easy way is using the Transforamation
you can see the columns and untick the nulls too

that is also easy but you need to do it 20 times
might be painfull but that wil make you familiar with the data in the columns